# in angular why does adding an ng-disabled to an ng-click button make it fire twice in a row

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic angular app that started to fire the `ng-click` twice in a row if I add an `ng-disabled` property (I wanted to prevent them from clicking the button twice).

Why does it fire twice in a row with that `ng-disabled` property?

```
<button ng-if="post._id" 
  class="button button-block button-outline" 
  ng-click="createPost()" 
  ng-disabled="isSaving">Update</button>
```

Comment: where does `isSaving` come from?

Comment: I think I know what you are doing, and I have a neat solution for this. What I do is switch the contents of the button with a spinner, and then in the method just say `if (isSaving) return;`

Comment: works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/NYLJuN5MyjtfFUv2uIzh

Comment: does it work properly without ng-disabled?

Comment: try to write type="button" because by default it is "submit".possibilty is that when you hit button it is submitting form directly

Comment: it works properly without ng-disabled, I set $scope.isSaving to true in the createPost method and then to false when the createPost method is finished

Comment: @CallumLinington yes I moved the isSaving check to the createPost method directly to avoid the ng-disabled ... it's a workable workaround, but still curious to know why the above wouldn't work in the first place

Answer (score -1):

I haven't got an answer for your problem, but I have another solution for your problem, here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DwzpzYaZROA2cBZXlbbD?p=preview)

I made a directive called `networkInfo` which sets the buttons content depending on whether the network call is being made or not.

It's not the perfect way, but a `link` function in 7 lines, and a button with two attributes on it ain't half bad.

The attribute `makingCall` is just a boolean of whether the call is being made.
The attribute `networkInfo` initiates the directive and fires the `link` function binding `makingCall` to its scope.

The function `update()` uses `$timeout` to imitate an asynchronous network call (using `$http` or something).

Firstly it checks `vm.working`, if it is `true` then don't make another network call. Then it sets it to `true`, to inform the directive that a call is now in process.

Finally it fires the `$timeout` which after `2secs` will set `vm.working` back to false to indicate the end of the network call.

Obviously I have used boostrap because that is what i'm more familiar with, however, like iconic its just stylings.